# Suggestions for a passport collage

Tags: collage, ideas

I have a few passport sized photos of a person, spanning his entire childhood. Could someone provide me with some creative ideas to make a collage or arrange these photos in a single image?

I am using Gimp, so I would appreciate if you could give me some pointers on how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I got married last year my colleges went on Facebook and downloaded loads of photos of me an my wife. They then made one of these http://www.photovisi.com/

They then printed it off and stuck it on my desk - I must say it was one of the coolest things!

Or if you really want a challenge then use Gimp with this [tutorial](http://digital-photography-school.com/create-a-collage-in-gimp) or use [these](http://www.gingerpixel.com/review/storyboard-templates/) in the tutorial

**UPDATE**: Photovisi Gallery Page is avalible [here](http://www.photovisi.com/gallery) - You need to drill past some of the spam to find "the good stuff"

This one is quite good!

[image]

Comment: Be sure to look at the [Photovisi galleries page](http://www.photovisi.com/gallery)